# How to draw three ellipses around three groups of points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ellipse

I know there are some posts asking the same question but the code did not work for me. This is my current code

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = iris$Petal.Length + iris$Petal.Width, 
y = iris$Sepal.Length + iris$Sepal.Width)) + 
geom_point(aes(colour = Species)) + 
xlab("Component 1") +      
ylab("Component 2") + 
ggtitle("Clustering by Species") + 
theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'), 
legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

As you can see, I am grouping with `colour = Species`. I  just wan to make ellipses around those data points with the same colour.

Comment: The following code seems to give you the expected output. `ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length + Petal.Width, y = Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width, colour = Species)) + geom_point() + stat_ellipse(type = "norm", linetype = 2)`.

Comment: That is correct. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. :)